# $f$-invariant subspaces for $\chi_f(X)=\mu_f(X)=X^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $n\geq 1\in\mathbb{N}$, let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}$-vector space and let $f:V\to V$ be a linear endomorphism such that 
$$\chi_f(X)=\mu_f(X)=X^n,$$ where $\chi_f$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of $f$ and $\mu_f$ denotes the according minimal polynomial.

**Assignment:** Find all $f$-invariant subspaces.

---

**My work so far:** I can see that $f$ is tridiagonalizable since $\chi_f$ splits so that gives us an $f$-invariant [flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(linear_algebra)) but what now? Are there more $f$-invariant subspaces of $V$?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: **Hint:** There is a $v\in V$ such that $f^n(v)=0$ but $f^{n-1}(v)\ne 0$.

Comment: @Berci Thanks, I can see that $\dim f^i(V)=\dim f^{i-1}(V)-1$ and your claim follows from that but how do I proceed from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For any vector $v \in V$, consider the set $S = \{v,f(v),\dots,f^k(v)\}$ where $f^k(v) \neq 0$ and $f^{k+1}(v) = 0$. Show that $S$ must be linearly independent.  Conclude that every invariant subspace of $f$ is the span of some $S$ of the form constructed above.  In other words, every invariant subspace has the form $f^j(V)$ for some $j$.

Comment: Thanks again, I was able to do the conclusion but now my problem is showing that $S$ is linearly independent. I have tried to use $f^k\neq 0$ and $f^{k+1}=0$ in order to show that for $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lambda_i f^i(v)=0$, $\lambda_{1\leq i\leq n-1}=0$. Could you maybe help me with that?

Comment: @user a hint: suppose that $\lambda_i = 0$ for $i < j$, and $\lambda_j \neq 0$.  Note that 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k}\lambda_i f^i(v) = 0 \implies
f^{k-j}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k}\lambda_i f^i(v)\right) = 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that only gives me $\lambda_j f^k(v)+f^{k-j}(\sum_{i\neq j} \lambda_i f^i(v))=0$ which I can't seem to draw to contradiction from.

Comment: Write that as $\lambda_j f^k(v)+f^{k-j}(\sum_{i> j} \lambda_i f^i(v))=0$ (see summation index). Bring $f^{k-j}$ into the sum.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see it. $\lambda_j f^k(v)\neq 0$ but $f^{k-j}(\sum)=0$ and so we have a contradiction (since the term in your comment equals zero). Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. I've always thought that that's a nifty argument; professor used it in my first lin alg class towards the end of the semester.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** There's a vector $v$, such that $v,f(v), \dots, f^{n-1}(v)$ form a basis.

If a vector in an invariant subspace with coordinates $(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n)$ in this basis has $a_i$ as the first nonzero coordinate, then all vectors with $0$ coordinates for indices $<i$ will belong to the subspace.